# Facebook App Rejection "publish_actions"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My App got rejected with "publish_actions" permission.

Reason mentioned as "People must enter all content in the user message field. Your app can't auto-populate the message field with any content...even if you allow users to edit the content before sharing. Please remove any pre-filled text from your shared content before resubmitting for review." I am using "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" and appending post parameters with message, description, and image link.

The flow is my websites (sports), private users can add an activity in which they select the date they perform the activity (sport), enter comment and upload the picture. The data is saved in my database and they are redirected to facebook, and their entered comment and picture (at my website) is posted as it is on their facebook account. Now i am out of idea how to proceed forward, with the rejection i have at hands. The comment is entered by user and they are posted at wall as it is, with no addition/subtraction.

Your guidance to proceed ahead will be highly highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe the video in this link will help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

If you are not pre-filling the messager parameter, I think it'll be fine for your to re-submit for review.

Best,

Jon